# Deriving Elliptic Curve Addition Formula

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

I just have a very basic question. For two distinct points $P_1, P_2$ with non-zero components on an elliptic curve $C$ given by $y^2 = x^3 + Ax + B$, I'm trying to derive the addition formula using the fact that the constant term of a monic cubic is equal to the negative of the product of the roots. Here's what I have so far, but I'm either making a mistake or missing the necessary algebraic trick.

Let $P_i = (x_i, y_i)$ for $i \in \{1,2\}$. Then the line from $P_1$ to $P_2$ is given by $y = m(x - x_1) + y_1$, where $m = (y_2 - y_1)/(x_2 - x_1)$. Then $$ y^2 = x^3 + Ax + B \implies f(x) = x^3 + Ax + B - (m(x-x_1) + y_1)^2$$ We can ignore all of the non-constant terms, so rewriting, we need to show that:
$ (-mx_1 + y_1)^2 - B $ is the product of the roots.
$$ m^2x_1^2 - 2mx_1y_1 + y_1^2 - B = m^2x_1^2 - 2mx_1y_1 + x_1^3 + Ax_1 $$
$$ \frac{m^2x_1^2 - 2mx_1y_1 + x_1^3 + Ax_1}{x_1x_2} = \frac{m^2x_1 - 2my_1 + x_1^2 + A}{x_2}$$
$$ \frac{m^2(x_2 + \frac{(y_1 - y_2)}{m}) - 2mx_1y_1 + x_1^3 + Ax_1}{x_1x_2} = \frac{m^2x_2 - my_1 - my_2 + x_1^2 + A}{x_2} $$
$$ = m^2 + \frac{-m(y_1 + y_2) + x^2_1 + A}{x_2} $$

I don't see how $\frac{-m(y_1 + y_2) + x^2_1 + A}{x_2} = -x_1 - x_2$ or even how to eliminate the $A$ term, so I must be making a mistake. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Given $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)\in E$, $x_1 \ne x_2$ you want a $t$ such that $(x_1+t (x_2-x_1),y_1+t (y_2-y_1)) \in E$. This is a cubic polynomial equation $P(t)=0$ with $3$ solutions : $t= 0,t=1$ and a 3rd one $T$, which means $P(t) = C t (t-1)(t-T)$, you obtain the value of  $T$ from $p(-1)= -2 C (T+1)$.

Comment: I don't see how to derive $x_3 = m^2 - x_1 - x_2$ from this.

Comment: ? The goal is to find $(x_3,y_3 )= (x_1+T (x_2-x_1),y_1+T (y_2-y_1)) \in E$. I changed your notation because your motivation for introducing $m$ and $ m(x - x_1) + y_1$ wasn't clean.

Comment: I'm working out of a problem in a book - have to derive the formula given, which is $x_3 = m^2 - x_1 - x_2$. I'm not understanding your notation either - are $P$ and $p$ different? What is $p(-1)$?

Comment: $(x_1+t (x_2-x_1),y_1+t (y_2-y_1)) \in E$ means $P(t) = (y_1+t (y_2-y_1))^2 - (x_1+t (x_2-x_1))^3-A (x_1+t (x_2-x_1))-B = 0$. Write $P(t) =  -(x_2-x_1)^3 t (t-1) (t-T)$ then $P(-1) = (x_2-x_1)^3 2(T+1)$ and your point is $(x_3,y_3 )= (x_1+T (x_2-x_1),y_1+T (y_2-y_1)) \in E$ and $(x_1,y_1)+(x_2,y_2)+(x_3,y_3) = O$ defines a group law

Comment: I don't think that that uses the fact that the constant term of a monic cubic is the negative of the product of the roots though, right?

Comment: It does with $P(-1) = (x_2-x_1)^32(T+1)$

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any experience w/ elliptic curves, so I'm probably being dense, but this doesn't really make sense. $P(t)=(y1+t(y2−y1))2−(x1+t(x2−x1))3−A(x1+t(x2−x1))−B=0$ - are you implying that $P(t) = 0$ for all $t$? Also, I'm still unclear on how to derive $x_3 = m^2 - x_1 - x_2$. $x_3$ is obviously on the line that you parametrized, but I need to give a solution that doesn't involve just defining a new $T$, and I'm unclear how to get to $m^2$ from $T$.

Comment: Further, if $y_3$ is meant to be the y-component of $P_1 + P_2$, the sign is wrong.

Comment: The coefficients of $P(t)$ are given (in term of $A,B,x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2)$) so $P(-1) = (x_2-x_1)^32(T+1)$ is such an expression

Comment: This doesn't really make sense and you keep editing your comments - the whole point of the problem is to define $x_3$ explicitly in terms of $x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2$. If you can do so, I'll stop commenting :), but your comments thus far aren't really comprehensible to me.

Comment: In term of $A,B,x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2$. That's what I did. $P(t)=(y_1+t (y_2-y_1))^2 - (x_1+t (x_2-x_1))^3-A (x_1+t (x_2-x_1))-B $ is a polynomial with known coefficients, so you know $P(-1)$

Comment: It's unclear that $P(-1)$ doesn't include $A,B$, when it should be in terms of $x_i,y_j$. You basically just asserted that there existed such a $T$ and left the answer in terms of that $T$, which is insufficient for what I'm looking for.

Comment: $A,B$ are given constants defining your elliptic curve, **everything** does depend on $A,B$. I gave **the** expression for $T$ in term of the given constants and parameters, there is no other expression (for $T$ and the $3$rd point)

Comment: No, given two points $P_1, P_2 \in C$, I **definitely** don't have to give an expression for $P_3$ that includes $A$ or $B$. Ex: $x_3 = (y_2 - y_1)^2/(x_2 - x_1)^2 - x_1 - x_2$, etc.

Comment: You asserted that there existed such a $T$ and that you could define it entirely in terms of the coefficients given. You didn't use the fact that the constant term of a monic cubic was the negative of the product of the roots, just that you could write a cubic polynomial with roots $a, b, c$ as $(x - a)(x -b)(x-c)$, which is a different fact. As should be clear in the original question, I'm looking for a way to derive the addition formula from that particular fact - there are much easier ways to derive it otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

I’m writing this after almost a glass of wine, hope I don’t get the rest of it on my face.

This is just not the strategy I know, and that is by comparison so much shorter than what you’ve written that I don’t have courage to read the $n+1$ comments.

The line joining the $P_i$ will be given by $\ell:Y=mX+n$ for $n$ a rational expression that need not concern us. Then to get the intersection of $\ell$ with the curve of course you look for the roots of $g(X)=X^3+AX+B-(mX+n)^2$, when you know that $(X-x_1)(X-x_2)$ divides this. When you divide, you get a quotient $X-(m^2-x_1-x_2)$. You don’t need to do the division out — you just need to make sure that the $X^2$-coefficients are all right.

There’s your desired formula. If you try to use the constant term of $g$, you will, in my setup, get bogged down with the formula for $n$, a mess. I really don’t recommend doing it this way unless you are interested in an intellectual exercise that is, in my mind, going the long way round Robin Hood’s barn.

Comment: Thank you, that makes perfect sense. I guess that you're using the fact that the roots of a monic cubic divide the constant term to save on doing all of the division - which makes me think that the problem intends for incredibly tedious algebra, but I'm self-studying, so I will remember your approach, rather than continuing to circle Robin Hood's barn.

Comment: Yes and no, @user1447447. What I was using was the fact that the next-highest coefficient is minus the sum of the roots. We know that two roots are the $x_i$, and the third is $-x_1-x_2+m^2$. I knew that the polynomial $(X-x_1)(X-x_2)$ must divide the cubic I mentioned; I’ve actually performed the full division, and the equality of the product of the three roots to the constant term in what you see above really did work out, but only after some tiresome manipulations, as I recall. It’s been a long time…