# Exercise on the sum of points on an elliptic curve from the book Elliptic Curves Number Theory and Cryptography

Tags: elliptic-curves, substitution, cubics

The book *Elliptic Curves Number Theory and Cryptography* by *Lawrence Washington* contains this two-parts exercise:

> a) Show that the constant term of a monic cubic polynomial is the
> negative of the product of the roots.
>
> b) Use (*a*) to derive the formula for the sum of two distinct points $P1$, $P2$ in the case that the x-coordinates $x_1$ and $x_2$ are nonzero, as in Section 2.2. Note that when one of these coordinates is 0, you need to divide by zero to obtain the usual formula.

This question is an **exact** duplicate of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2947632/deriving-elliptic-curve-addition-formula) that got no satisfactory answer.
Considering that question is lacking the book context and that reviving a 3 year old question is very hard, I'm writing my own.
Eventually, if this question gets an answer, we can make the old question a duplicate of this.

Part (a) is very easy but, shamefully, part (b) is giving me trouble.

In Section 2.2 the author is given two points $P1 = (x_1, y_1)$, $P2 = (x_2, y_2)$ (with $x_1 \neq x_2$) on an elliptic curve $y^2 = x^3 + Ax + B$.
They find the line through these points to be $y = m(x - x_1) + y_1$, with $m = (y_2 - y_1)/(x_2 - x_1)$.
They proceed with intersecting the line and the elliptic curve to obtain $x^3 - m^2x^2 + (A + 2m^2x_1 + 2my_1)x + (B - m^2x_1^2 + 2mx_1y_1 - y_1^2) = 0$.
Two of the roots of this equation are $x_1$ and $x_2$ by construction and the third is found by exploiting the fact that (for a monic cubic equation like this one) $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = m^2$ and hence:
$$
x_3 = m^2 - x_1 - x_2\tag{1}\label{eq1}
$$

I *believe* part (b) is asking me to redo the passages above but using the fact that the roots $r_{1..3}$of a monic cubic equation $x^3 + ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ satisfy $r_1 r_2 r_3 = -c$.

I set:
$$
\begin{equation}
x_1 x_2 x_3 = m^2x_1^2 + y_1^2 - 2mx_1y_1 - B\tag{*}\label{eq0}
\end{equation}
$$

Then I substituted $y_1^2$ with $x_1^3 + Ax_1 + B$:
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
x_1 x_2 x_3 &= m^2x_1^2 + x_1^3 + Ax_1 + B - 2mx_1y_1 - B \\
  &= x_1(m^2x_1 + x_1^2 + A  - 2my_1)  \\
x_2 x_3 &= m^2x_1 + x_1^2 + A  - 2my_1 \\
x_3 &= \frac{m^2x_1 + x_1^2 + A  - 2my_1}{x_2} \\
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

But now I'm stuck.
Equation $\eqref{eq2}$ seems to be correct as it gives me the same values of $\eqref{eq1}$ (tested with [this](https://pastebin.com/8b0ty2pL) code) but I don't see how to turn $\eqref{eq2}$ into $\eqref{eq1}$.

I also tried factoring the binomial square in $\eqref{eq0}$, replacing $B$ with $y_2^2 - x_2^3 - Ax_2$ and rewriting $m$ but got nowhere.

How to get $\eqref{eq1}$ from $\eqref{eq2}$?

Comment: I'm going to sleep now, I'll be able to answer any comment tomorrow. Sorry for that.

Comment: My guess is that to do this exercise you don't need to show that (1) and (2) always lead to the same value of $x_3$. They simply do, because the roots of the cubic satisfy the Vieta relations $x_1+x_2+x_3=-a$, $x_1x_2x_3=-c$, $x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_3=b$, and that's all. I further guess that you are to derive a different formula for the sum of two points that is valid under these circumstances ($x_1x_2\neq0$). That other formula may be used in some situations.

But, it is possible that I'm wrong. I'm simply not sure of what the point of this exercise is :-(

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you for your comment, I'm not sure either :) The fact that part (a) is so elementary is making me question if I'm really reading part (b) correctly.